# What does the "c" in strcspn stand for?

Tags: c

`strspn("string", "chars")` gives the length of the initial span in string consisting of characters in "chars", while `strcspn("string", "chars")` gives the length of the initial span in string consisting of characters not in "chars".

What stands the "c" for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What does the “c” in strcspn stand for?

For the word "complementary".

From [cppreference strcspn](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn):

> The function name stands for "complementary span" because the function searches for characters not found in src, that is the complement of src.

Comment: Thanks, was not in the first 10 references for strcspn on google :-(

Comment: @notan Interesting that the FreeBSD man page does describe it that way but the Linux man page doesn't even mention it.